# Sign in with Google+ flow

Tags: javascript, google-plus

I am trying to wrap my head around the G+ Sign-in flow, but I am not sure if I have gotten it right.

I have mainly been looking at [this page](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/server-side-flow)

Where in that flow can I connect to my own database and fetch things such as username and permissions, and what am I supposed to store as identifier in my database (to quickly identify them next logon)? Should I talk to the G+ API and get their G+ ID and then store that (together with the data I want to store about the user)?

How would the flow look the second time they sign-on?
I need something that will in the end give me the G+ ID (if I used that) so that I can find them in my DB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quickest way to get going with Google+ API calls is [the Google+ Quickstarts](https://developers.google.com/+/quickstarts). These samples will get you going with code that should be ready to copy and paste into your applications. I'll shortly discuss the flows demonstrated in the apps.

As with OAuth 2.0, the goal is to get a bearer token (access token in OAuth 2.0) to authorize API calls. The token can be retrieved a number of ways, but the most important for sign-in using the Google+ Sign-In button is code exchange.

The first time a user encounters your site (let's call it sign-up) the flow will be code exchange. The code exchange pattern is:

1. User reaches your site
2. User clicks preferred authorization (Google+ Sign-In)
3. User is presented with consent / authorization screen
4. Code is returned from JavaScript to the web client
5. The Web client (HTML/JavaScript) passes the authorization code to your server
6. The server exchanges the code for a refresh and access token then caches these tokens

At this point, your server has an access token. This means that you can make API calls (e.g. plus.people.get('me'), which gets the signed-in user's profile) to Google based on the user permissions granted to your app.

The user should now be authorized with your server and authentication should happen based on the user's session and so forth. However, now you have a new problem, what happens when the user accesses your site again from a new browser, or otherwise destroys their session?

This is a great time to transition to the next important flow: the authentication (let's just call it "sign-in") flow. For sign-in, you should have the client pass your server an authentication credential (again a bearer token) and then verify the credential before establishing a new session for the user in your database.

The [verify token examples on the Google+ Github page](https://github.com/googleplus) demonstrate concise code for sending and verifying ID tokens.

Let's discuss the details of one approach to passing a type of bearer token, the ID token, for authentication.

1. User signs in to your site
2. The Google+ Sign-In button returns an ID token in a callback
3. The client securely passes the ID token to the server
4. The server verifies the ID token*
5. The client session is then authenticated

The steps for * are best put in another question, however a typical set of tests includes:

1. Verify the token's certificate is Google's
2. Verify the client id is for this app
3. Verify the user has an account on your site (optional, do this if you need offline access)
4. Verify the token hasn't expired

Hope that clears things up for the two.

There is one final flow you should be aware of, used for offline API access, token refresh. Token refresh happens when you have a refresh token and an expired access token. For Google's implementation of OAuth 2.0, access tokens expire after 3600 seconds (1 hour). Because these tokens expire, you need to be able to get new access tokens when your stored access tokens expire. To do this, you pass three bits to Google:

1. Refresh token (retrieved from code exchange)
2. Client ID (retrieved from the [Google developer console](https://developers.google.com/+/quickstarts))
3. Client secret (again, retrieved from the [Google developer console](https://developers.google.com/+/quickstarts))

These parts are passed to the Google OAuth server and the server will then return a fresh access token that you can use for offline API access.

There's a wealth of information on this topic, see also:

- [Using the one-time code flow for Google+ Sign-In](http://gusclass.com/blog/2013/03/22/using-the-hybrid-clientserver-flow-with-google-sign-in/)
- [Google+ Developer documentation, Token Verification](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/token-verification)

Comment: This was exactly the answer I wanted, thanks for clarifying everything, especially the verify part (had missed that one)! Do you recommend that I install and use their "google-api-python-client" (both dev and production) or should I write my own requests? EDIT: Saw that you work for Google, so I assume that is a yes (haha)!

Comment: @fgblomqvist - Yes, Google's client libraries are the way to go. For Python, this holds even more true because the client library is out of Beta, meaning it's supported by Google.

Comment: I noticed the library is not available for Python 3. I guess I will have to code it from scratch then.

Comment: Scratch that, I found a half-done port [here](https://github.com/enorvelle/GoogleApiPython3x), time to get to work!